Anyone knows how to use lifecycle hooks in Strapi 5?
I didn't find the documentation that explains this in Strapi 5, so i don't know if it changed since Strapi 4.
path of the code: src/api/post/content-types/post/lifecycle.js
const axios = require('axios');

module.exports = {
    async afterCreate(event) {
        await axios.post('https://api.netlify.com/build_hooks/key');
    },

    async afterUpdate(event) {
        await axios.post('https://api.netlify.com/build_hooks/key');
    },
}

When you use the method post on this link, netlify will automatic build your application with the new content. but it's not working

In Strapi v5, lifecycle hooks work similarly to Strapi v4, Possible flaws/fixes in your case might be :

Its lifecycles.js and not lifecycle.js in src/api/post/content-types/post/lifecycle.js
Axios post request body and structure.
Use try catch block and console the error in catch block.

Hope it works
